# Ionic 3 - Error in logout

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am already doing a login on my server in digital ocean.
I have a HomePage that show some user properties (`{{user.name}}` for example).
When I fire the logout function, that is located in my app.component:

```
logout(){
    if(this.userProvider.isAuthenticated()){
      this.nav.setRoot(SigninPage);
      this.menu.close();
      this.userProvider.logout();
    }
}
```

The application crashes with the following error:

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null**

It seems that HomePage still exists

To logout today, I'm refreshing the application using

```
 window.location.reload();
```

But, using that the app user will have to log everytime that the application inits

Comment: you can use this code to remove every last page : this.navCtrl.push('AccountcreatedPage').then(() => {
                  const startIndex = this.navCtrl.getActive().index - 1;
                  this.navCtrl.remove(startIndex, 1);
                });

Comment: can you add the `logout()` function code in userProvider?

Comment: @NavinRai thanks... i solved the problem adding:
if(this.userProvider.isAuthenticated()){
      this.menu.close();
      this.nav.setRoot(SigninPage).then(()=>{
        this.userProvider.logout();
      });
    }

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved changing the code to:

```
if(this.userProvider.isAuthenticated()){
  this.menu.close();
  this.nav.setRoot(SigninPage).then(()=>{
    this.userProvider.logout();
  });
}
```

Thanks